# React native firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.password) not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I am trying to sign in in my react native app through firebase auth but I am not able sign in.
I am getting only the default error message in all the cases, even if I am entering the correct credentials. Can anyone help me find the error

> ```
> export const loginuser = async ({ email, password }) => {
> try {
>   await firebase
>     .auth()
>     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
>     .then(function(user) {
>       temp = user;
>
>     });
>   return temp;
> } catch (error) {
>   switch (error.code) {
>     case "auth/invalid-email":
>       return {
>         error: "Invalid email address format."
>       };
>     case "auth/user-not-found":
>       return {
>         error: "User not found."
>       };
>     case "auth/wrong-password":
>       return {
>         error: "Wrong password entered."
>       };
>
>     default:
>       return {
>         error: "Authentication Failed. Try again later."
>       };
>   }
> }   
> };
> ```

I am calling this function from my login.js file

```
const [enteredEmail, setEmail] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });
const [enteredPass, setPass] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });

const [error, setError] = useState("");

const onLoginPressed=async()=>{

        const emailError=emailValidator(enteredEmail.value);
        const passError=passwordValidator(enteredPass.value);

        if(emailError||passError){
            setEmail({ ...enteredEmail, error: emailError });
            setPass({ ...enteredPass, error: passError });
        }
        const response=await loginuser({
            email:enteredEmail.value,
            password:enteredPass.value});
            if(response.error){
            setError(response.error);
        }
        else {
            navigation.navigate("Home");
        }
};
```

Comment: So, what is the error code that causes the switch to fall through to the default?  I suggest also logging the `entire` error object to see what went wrong.

Comment: you haven't defined `temp`. Maybe that is the error being caught in the catch block

Comment: use "firebase": "^7.14.1" version, it works